# Calculating total-items in AngularJs Pagination (ui.bootstrap) doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use `controllerAs` and avoid using the `$scope` as a model.
I want to add pagination in my search result. I have a paging object in my controller as below, which will be shared with angular service and then with the server API.

```
 vm.paging = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        totalCount: 0
    };
```

`totalCount` will be set by server and then be read from response.
My pagination in html:

```
  <pagination total-items="ctrl.pageCount"
              items-per-page="ctrl.paging.pageSize"
              ng-model="ctrl.paging.pageNumber"
              class="pagination-sm"
              boundary-links="true"
              ng-change="ctrl.find()">
              </pagination>
```

I calculate `pageCount` in controller as below:

```
vm.pageCount = function () {
        return Math.ceil(vm.paging.totalCount / vm.paging.pageSize);
    };
```

But it doesn't work. when I set `vm.pageCount = 1000;` it works. It seems the problem is the function. How can I fix this problem? (the buttons are disabled and It should return 100 pages, not one! )
[image]

**Update**: Sample [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tKksD2piFTG5siEJQc6G?p=preview)

Comment: can you post all the pagination code or make a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: Update: I added sample plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! Of course, with the guidance of my colleague :) . As in my plunk (script.js), I hadn't Initialized the `vm.paging` object after the response, so the computing was based on default values in `vm.paging`. Since `totalCount` was 0, always the Division result was 1 and I had just one page. So I edited the `vm.find` body as below:

```
vm.find = function () {
            vm.result.length = 0;     
vm.findingPromise = myService.find(vm.filter, vm.paging);
            vm.findingPromise
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.result = response.data.result;
                    // EDITED PART:
                    vm.paging = response.data.paging;
                    //   

                }, function (response) {
                    var r = response;
                    ngNotify.set('Some problems occurred!',
                        {
                            type: 'error',
                            position: 'top',
                            sticky: true
                        });
                });
```

And also, I couldn't take advantages of `uib-pagination`, but when I replaced `ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js` anywhere I was using `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` before, it works correctly.
Also I removed the function of computing `pageCount`. With many thanks to **svarog**.

Answer (score 2):

1. you CAN use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression ([IFEE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)) to get your `vm.pageCount` like so

   ```
   ctrl.pageCount = (function() {
       return Math.ceil(ctrl.paging.totalItems / ctrl.paging.pageSize);
   })();
   ```
2. but **you don't need** to calculate `pageCount` and put it under `total-items` (the amount of pages in the pagination will be calculated automatically), you should provide it the length of you record array instead!

lets say if you get table data `vm.data` from http, you should place the length of this data inside `total-items` like so

```
     total-items="vm.data.length"
```

**HTML**

```
    <uib-pagination total-items="ctrl.paging.totalItems"
          items-per-page="ctrl.paging.pageSize"
          ng-model="ctrl.paging.pageNumber"
          class="pagination-sm"
          boundary-links="true"
          ng-change="ctrl.find()">
          </uib-pagination>
```

**JS**

```
    ctrl.paging = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        totalItems: response.length // this is your remote data
    };
```

I've made this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ESdfyP0gaXkzs4180u1X?p=preview) for you

**EDIT 1**

since version 0.14.0, the directives are prefixed by `uib-`

> Since version 0.14.0 we started to prefix all our components. If you are upgrading from ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 or earlier, check our migration guide.

so you should also use `uib-pagination` (instead of `pagination`) because your plunk uses the 1.3.2 version.

Comment: ctrl is define in my html page like this: 'findCtrl as ctrl'. findCtrl is mycontroller name. but vm is define in controller body:'var vm = this;'

Comment: should I use  uib-pagination? does it need to change any configuration or just I should replace the pagination tag with this?

Comment: I tested IFEE mode, but it doesn't work yet. I have one and just one page, but when I trace in console of debug mode, the response is completely correct.  I added sample plunker in question .

Comment: yes, of course you should use `uib-pagination`. i'll edit the answer

Comment: your plunk throws errors, i didn't mean you should wrap your entire script in IIFE, i meant you shouldn't even use `ctrl.pageCount`, just provide valid logical values to `total-items` and `items-per-page` as in my plunk.