# Problems with total number of pages in uib-pagination in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination

There is an older thread on a similar topic [Calculating total-items in AngularJs Pagination (ui.bootstrap) doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153975/calculating-total-items-in-angularjs-pagination-ui-bootstrap-doesnt-work-corr) which doesn't answer my problem and I don't know how to add to it.

We have a complex smList directive which has the following html at the bottom of the page

```
<div class="text-center" ng-show="vm.table.pageCount > 1">
  <ul uib-pagination 
      total-items="vm.table.totalCount"
      ng-model="vm.table.pageNumber"
      items-per-page="vm.table.pageSize"
      max-size="5"
      rotate="false"
      ng-change="vm.selectPage()"
      previous-text="@Labels.previous"
      next-text="@Labels.next"></ul>
</div>
```

In certain scenarios the number of total pages doesn't update correctly. Say, I ran a search with a filter and got 4 pages, when removed the filter, so I should get more pages (more than 5). I'm still seeing the same 4 pages even though when I trace the code I see correct numbers in the controller table.totalCount.

What should we do to fix the problem? Should we always set the totalCount to 0 prior to running the search?

In the search code which returns result from the server we have the following:

```js
.then(function (data) {
                log.debug("After main search return...");

                self.results = data.list;
                self.table.totalCount = data.totalCount;
                self.table.pageCount = data.pageCount;
                self.table.pageSize = data.pageSize;
                self.table.pageNumber = data.pageNumber;                

                self.showResults = true;
```

May be instead of setting total items we can just use the pagecount returned from the server (as we do our math there too)? Is there a way to set pagecount for uib-pagination instead of total-items
?

Comment: can you post your complete codes ?

Comment: What do you mean here? Both the template and the directive is very complex, it's impossible to post it. I added setting totalCount to 0 before doing search, but that didn't solve the problem. It seems the problem only occurs if I click on the row in the list to display the edit form first.

Comment: so we need to guess your code in your controller ?

Comment: I've added a bit of code into my post. As I said, that code is in the directive (in its controller), not in the page controller.

Comment: have you tried removeing `max-size="5"` from the `html` ? ( the `ul` attribute )

Comment: No, haven't tried it yet. Is is the maximum number of pages to display before using ... ? It it default 5 and doesn't need to be set?

Comment: it defaults to `null` and it will display the max of pages possible in the container, check the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) to see how set the limit of pages and to add `prev/next` if you want

Comment: Ok, tried it - didn't help and I got all 11 pages displayed in both cases.

Comment: I've tried various modes but still got the same problem. I also added self.table.totalCount = 0; and then self.table.totalCount = data.totalCount; but still no go. May be the directive stops watching this property at some point? It looks like the problem only occurs after I open an edit form first (which is ui-view)

Comment: I've added at the  bottom of the page <pre>Calculated number of pages: { {{numPages}}</pre> and used num-pages=numPages and I can get that same bug consistently and I see the wrong number following my steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE. Seems like the issue was in our directive RowClick code. Once I commented out one line of code the problem seems to be solved.

So, this is not an answer, but I think the bug only shows up if I open my edit form.

The index page looks like this:

```html
<div ng-controller="DynamicRulesController">
    <div ng-controller="dynamicRulesSearchController">
        <data-sm:list data-name="dynamicRules"
                      data-table="table"
                      data-hide-hidden-filter="true"
                      data-show-search="true"
                      data-can-hide-search="false"
                      data-on-before-new-record="onBeforeNewRecord"  
                      data-dont-go-to-new-state="true"                   
                      data-pk="ruleId"
                      data-param-id="id"
                      data-heading="heading">
        </data-sm:list>     
    </div>

    <div class="edit-container ng-cloak" ng-show="!isEditLoading" ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>
```

As long as I stay on the index page and don't open the Edit form (ui-view), the pagination works correctly. As soon as I open my Edit form, it stops working. Something related to the states and ui-view seems to interfere.